# In triangle abc,angle BAC is 22 degrees. A circle with centre O has AB produced,AC produced and BC tangents. Find the number of degrees in angle BOC.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In triangle abc,angle BAC is 22 degrees. A circle with centre O has AB produced,AC produced and BC tangents. Find the number of degrees in angle BOC.

I am not able to interpret it. Plz help me in making the figure.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use words, yes, pretty ridiculous!

Draw triangle $ABC$ like this. Draw $BC$ as a horizontal line segment. Put the  point $A$  somewhere **above** that line segment.

Extend $AB$ "downward,", also extend $AC$ downward. Now imagine drawing a circle in the chunk **BC**, touching $BC$ from **below**, and touching $AB$ and $AC$ extended.

This is one of the **excircles** of $\triangle ABC$. Look at the [Wikipedia article on excircles.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle) It has the nice picture that I am unable to supply. And a lot of useful additional information. In Wikipedia's picture, the excircle you are asked about is vaguely north-east of $\triangle ABC$.

**Remark:** Now you have the picture. If after a *serious* attempt at solving the problem, you need a hint, please leave a message.

Comment: Is O here incentre

Comment: No, here $O$ is one of the three excentres.

Comment: then how can an excircle  have 3 tangents as the sides of the triangle..?

Comment: Two of them are sides *extended*. Please look at the picture in the link I gave. You will find hundreds of other hits, if you google **excircle**. Most of them will have pictures.

Comment: i have tried very had plzz help now.!!!

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Join $O$ to $B$, to $C$, and the points of tangency. Remember that if a line is tangent, the line from centre to point of tangency is perpendicular to the tangent line. Call the point of tangency to $AB$ extended $P$, to $BC$ extended $Q$, to $BC$ (not extended) $R$. There will be a couple of pairs of congruent triangles. Let angle at $B$ be $\beta$, angle at $C$ be $\gamma$. The external angle at $B$ is $180-\beta$, and gets split into two equal parts by $OB$. Similar phenomenon at $C$. (Cont)

Comment: a figure if made would be very good....mark that on the figure.. thnx..

Comment: (Cont) Conclude that the angle $BOC$ is $180-(90-\beta/2)-(90\gamma/2)=(\beta+\gamma)/2$. But if we know the angle at $A$, we know $\beta+\gamma$. You should end up with $(180-22)/2$.